# PyBullet: All link arrays need to be same size

Tags: python, physics-engine, bulletphysics, pybullet

When trying to create a Multibody with a base and a link (or even more links) i get the error from the title.

I checked that all the length of arrays(lists) are the same and made a super simple version with only a base and one link.

```
p.createMultiBody(baseMass=1, 
baseCollisionShapeIndex=1, 
baseVisualShapeIndex=1, 
basePosition = [0,0,0], 
baseOrientation=[0,0,0,1], 
linkMasses=[1],  
linkCollisionShapeIndices=[2],
linkVisualShapeIndices=[2], 
linkPositions=[[0,0,1]], 
linkOrientations=[[0,0,0,0]], 
linkParentIndices=[1], 
linkJointTypes=[p.JOINT_FIXED], 
linkJointAxis=[[0,0,1]])

pybullet.error: All link arrays need to be same size.
```

If you have any hint what I'm doing wrong, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the arguments `linkInertialFramePositions` and `linkInertialFrameOrientations`.  These arguments are labelled as optional in the [Quickstart Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10sXEhzFRSnvFcl3XxNGhnD4N2SedqwdAvK3dsihxVUA/edit#), but must be provided if the body has any joints.